# java xslt transformation local-name

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, transformation

I have a xslt stylesheet which should do some generic transformation. The relevant part is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:template match="myForm/*">
    <xsl:element name="formularfeld">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:local-name()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet works as expected when I run in XMLSpy. However when I call from Java 8 SE or ServiceMix 7 I get
ERROR:  'Klasse "xpath-functions" kann nicht gefunden werden.'
Externe Methode "xpath-functions.localName" kann nicht gefunden werden (muss "public" sein).
FATAL ERROR:  'Externe Methode "xpath-functions.localName" kann nicht gefunden werden (muss "public" sein).'
(Class xpath-functions cannot be found. External method xpath-funckions.localName cannot be found)

```
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(xmlOutWriter);
        Reader inputReader = new StringReader(input);
        Reader xsltReader = new StringReader(stylesheet);
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(xsltReader);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        transformer.setParameter("timestamp", timestamp);
        Source inputSource = new StreamSource(inputReader);
        transformer.transform(inputSource, streamResult);
```

Comment: If  you want to use XSLT in the Java world then Saxon 9 is always an option. The built-in Xalan only supports XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor. In XSLT 1.0, there is no namespace for functions. Even in XSLT 2.0 the namespace is optional. You can simply change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:local-name()" />
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
```

and remove the `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` declaration.